# How to add custom button on Product & Cart Page on Open Cart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am creating an extention to add custom button on Product & Cart page. I have created a extension through which i can set fields, now i want to display the button on those pages. I try one sample code but it is not working, i don't understand where to place that file. here is the code:

`

```
<name>ClearShoppingCart by iSenseLabs</name>
<version>1.0 (Initial)</version>
<link>https://isenselabs.com</link>
<author>iSenseLabs</author>
<code>isenselabs_clearshoppingcart</code>

<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/cart.twig">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[<a href="{{ cart }}"><strong><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>]]></search>
        <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function clearCart() {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/clearcart',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(json) {
                  $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                  if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                      location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                  } else {
                      $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                  }
              }
          });
        }
        </script>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="clearCart();" ><strong><i class="fa fa-times"></i> {{button_clearcart }}</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{{ cart }}"><strong><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[public function add() {]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        public function clearcart() {
            $this->load->language('checkout/cart');
            $json = array();
            $this->cart->clear();
            $total = 0;
            
            unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['reward']);

            $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), $this->cart->countProducts() + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) ? count($this->session->data['vouchers']) : 0), $this->currency->format($total, $this->config->get('config_currency')));

            if (isset($this->request->get['shoppingcart']) && $this->request->get['shoppingcart']=='true') {
                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
            } else {
                $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
                $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
            }
        }
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="catalog/controller/common/cart.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[$this->load->language('common/cart');]]></search>
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        $data['button_clearcart'] = $this->language->get('button_clearcart');
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[$this->load->language('checkout/cart');]]></search>
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        $data['button_clearcart'] = $this->language->get('button_clearcart');
        $data['link_clearcart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart/clearcart', 'shoppingcart=true');
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="catalog/language/en-gb/common/cart.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[$_['text_recurring'] = 'Payment Profile';]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        $_['button_clearcart']  = 'Clear Cart';
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="catalog/language/en-gb/checkout/cart.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[$_['column_total']             = 'Total';]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        $_['button_clearcart']  = 'Clear Cart';
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/cart.twig">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[{% if modules %}]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[
            <a href="{{ link_clearcart }}" class="btn btn-default" title="{{button_clearcart}}">{{button_clearcart}}</a>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

`

i am saving it with install.xml and make it zip. it installed successfully but nothing comes up.

Comment: After installation you must refresh modifications and clear cache in OC Admin. The browser cache also must be cleared.

Comment: i made it work, is there any way i can add custom button on product page below add to cart button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to your xml something like this:

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.twig">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[<button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="{{ text_loading }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">{{ button_cart }}</button>]]></search>
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[
            <a href="{{ link_clearcart }}" class="btn btn-default" title="{{button_clearcart}}">{{button_clearcart}}</a>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: i have added the code and when extension is installed, again it shows nothing, actually i just want to show simple button on product page and cart page, i will get the values from specific fields

Comment: your code  <modification></modification> tags missing